# Cannot pass variables to django home template from another template in app

Tags: python, django, templates, variables, cookiecutter-django

I've got a simple view, form and 2 templates in my django (1.9.2) project
The template that view is passed works like a charm, iterates through and displays wanted value without problems.

Yet when I want to include this template into another one the iteration does not occur. I've tried using `{% include with %}` but maybe I'm not doing it right.

The template that is the for the homepage is placed in project template folder, while the template to be included is inside the app

news/models.py:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.title
```

news/views.py:

```
from news.models import News
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext

def news(request):
    posts = News.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'news.html',{'posts':posts })
```

news/templates/news.html:

```
{% load i18n %} 
{% block content %}
<h2>News</h2>
    :D
    {% for post in posts %}
        {{ post.title }}
        {{ post.body }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

templates/home.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">

  {% include "news.html" with posts=posts %}

    </div>
</section>
{% include "footer.html" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

When checking at http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/ everything is fine,
but at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ only :D is displayed

No idea how to tackle this
Thanks :^)

EDIT:

For the Home I actually use only template and in urls it looks like this:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html') ,  name="home")
```

Also for the base I use cookie-cutter django from cookiecutter-django

Should I define view somewhere for home also?

Comment: What does  your home view look like?

Comment: Please share your home view

Comment: I can't find any :( should I define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when you are using

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html') ,  name="home")
```

You are not defining `posts` at all. To make it working you have to pass context with `posts` to this `name="home"` view but you are using default `as_view` which doesn't pass `posts`.

I would make it like so:

news/urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', views.home,  name="home")
```

news/views.py:

```
from news.models import News
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext

def home(request):
   posts = News.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts':posts })
```

news/templates/news.html:

```
{% load i18n %} 
{% block inner_content %}
<h2>News</h2>
    :D
    {% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.body }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock inner_content %}
```

templates/home.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
<section id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">

  {% include "news.html" with posts=posts %}

    </div>
</section>
{% include "footer.html" %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: {% block content %} should be {% block inner_content %}... and {% endblock inner_content %}